# Set permissions for file in lua

Tags: linux, lua, permissions

I use `os.rename()` for move file from old address of file like `/root/filexxx` to `/var/www/html/filexxx`.
Transfered file didn't accessible for download in user browser run on Apache2 server side because permissions for file also `660`

How i can change permissions with lua in my script for `filexxx` to can readable for users in my website  like `664`

Comment: `os.execute('chmod o+r "/var/www/html/filexxx"')`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks man